# Cannot compile (using make) a driver on debian but it works on ubuntu (different computers so it might not be an OS problem)

Tags: debian, drivers, make, ethernet

I have been trying to install debian on an old PC but I had to install the driver for the ethernet module which is a realtek rtl8111 based module. I found a driver, but when I try to `make` it (after extracting it), (i tried both an autorun script it had and the Makefile itself using both `make` and `make clean`), I get this error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'clean'. Stop.
```

I tried installing the same driver on my Ubuntu laptop and it worked right away.
Is there a solution to this problem?

Note 1: the driver is the *GBE Ethernet LINUX driver r8168 for kernel up to 5.6 * from [www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software](http://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software)

Note 2: the OSes are ubuntu 21.10 and debian 11

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more detail. What is this driver? What did you download for it? Did you run `make` or `make clean`? Where did you run whatever you run? In what directory? What were the contents of this directory? How did you install on Ubuntu? Did you also try to compile from source on the Ubuntu machine or did you install from the repositories?

Comment: @terdon is it ok now?

Comment: Thanks, but no. We need to know: i) the _exact_ command you ran. Was it `make` or `make clean`? ii) the contents of the directory you ran the command in. Is there a `Makefile` there? iii) What package you downloaded from the link you gave, and what you did with what you downloaded.

Comment: If you want, we can go into a chat room quickly and sort out the details. Let me know if you want to do that.

Comment: @terdon can we do that now?